# Harmonic and Geometric means with Jensen inequality

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, probability-theory, statistics

Let be $a_1,...,a_n$ positive numbers, we need to proof with Jensen inequality that:

$$\frac{n}{\sum _{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{a_i} } \leq \left( \prod_{i=1}^{n}  a_i \right)^{1/n} $$

Let be $x_i= \frac{1}{a_i}$ and $g(X)=ln(X)$ with density $P(X=x_i)=p_i=\frac{1}{n}$.

We know that $ \ ln(.)$  is a concave function with Jensen we have:

$$ln \left(\frac{\sum x_i}{n}\right) \geq \frac{\sum ln(x_i)}{n}  \implies \frac{\sum \frac{1}{a_i} }{n} \geq exp  \left(\frac{ \sum ln( \frac{1}{a_i} )}{n} \right) = \prod \left(\frac{1}{a_i}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}} $$

what is the mistake?

Comment: No mistake, you just need to complete the proof by flipping both sides of the inequality (applying the ${}^{-1}$ power) and flipping the direction of the inequality simultaneously

Comment: Thank youu, it´s correct :D